# Should MySQL have its timezone set to UTC?

Tags: mysql, time, utc

Follow up question of
https://serverfault.com/questions/191331/should-servers-have-their-timezone-set-to-gmt-utc

Should the MySQL timezone be set to UTC or should it be set to be the same timezone as the server or PHP is set? (If it is not UTC)

What are the pros and cons?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1650406/175071 shares good reasons for using UTC

Comment: UTC is not a timezone. UTC is a standard, GMT is a timezone. https://zachholman.com/talk/utc-is-enough-for-everyone-right

Comment: Another great reason to use UTC
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161416/why-does-mysql-calculate-a-wrong-timestamp-when-using-from-unixtime

Comment: A reason to not use UTC: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/

Answer (score 644, accepted):

It seems that it does not matter what timezone is on the server as long as you have the time set right for the current timezone, know the timezone of the datetime columns that you store, and are aware of the issues with daylight savings time.

On the other hand if you have control of the timezones of the servers you work with then you can have everything set to UTC internally and never worry about timezones and DST, at least when it comes to storing internal time.

Here are some notes I collected of how to work with timezones as a form of cheatsheet for myself and others which might influence what timezone the person will choose for his/her server and how he/she will store date and time.

## MySQL Timezone Cheatsheet

Notes:

1. Changing the timezone **will not change the stored datetime or
   timestamp**, but it will select a different datetime from
   timestamp columns
2. **Warning!** UTC has leap seconds, these look like '2012-06-30 23:59:60' and can
   be added randomly, with 6 months prior notice, due to the slowing of
   the earths rotation
3. GMT confuses seconds, which is why UTC was invented.
4. **Warning!** different regional timezones might produce the same datetime value due
   to daylight savings time
5. The timestamp column only supports dates 1970-01-01 00:00:01 to 2038-01-19 03:14:07 UTC, due to [a limitation](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12654).
6. Internally a [MySQL timestamp column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) is stored as [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) but
   when selecting a date MySQL will automatically convert it to the
   current session timezone.

   When storing a date in a timestamp, MySQL will assume that the date
   is in the current session timezone and convert it to UTC for
   storage.
7. MySQL can store partial dates in datetime columns, these look like
   "2013-00-00 04:00:00"
8. MySQL stores "0000-00-00 00:00:00" if you set a datetime column as
   NULL, unless you specifically set the column to allow null when you
   create it.
9. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1650910/175071)

### To select a timestamp column in UTC format

no matter what timezone the current MySQL session is in:

```
SELECT 
CONVERT_TZ(`timestamp_field`, @@session.time_zone, '+00:00') AS `utc_datetime` 
FROM `table_name`
```

You can also set the sever or global or current session timezone to UTC and then select the timestamp like so:

```
SELECT `timestamp_field` FROM `table_name`
```

### To select the current datetime in UTC:

```
SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP();
SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP;
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), @@session.time_zone, '+00:00');
```

Example result: `2015-03-24 17:02:41`

### To select the current datetime in the session timezone

```
SELECT NOW();
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
```

### To select the timezone that was set when the server launched

```
SELECT @@system_time_zone;
```

Returns "MSK" or "+04:00" for Moscow time for example, there is (or was) a MySQL bug where if set to a numerical offset it would not adjust the Daylight savings time

### To get the current timezone

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP);
```

It will return 02:00:00 if your timezone is +2:00.

### To get the current UNIX timestamp (in seconds):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

### To get the timestamp column as a UNIX timestamp

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timestamp`) FROM `table_name`
```

### To get a UTC datetime column as a UNIX timestamp

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(`utc_datetime`, '+00:00', @@session.time_zone)) FROM `table_name`
```

### Get a current timezone datetime from a positive UNIX timestamp integer

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(`unix_timestamp_int`) FROM `table_name`
```

### Get a UTC datetime from a UNIX timestamp

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(`unix_timestamp_int`), @@session.time_zone, '+00:00') 
FROM `table_name`
```

### Get a current timezone datetime from a negative UNIX timestamp integer

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('1970-01-01 00:00:00',INTERVAL -957632400 SECOND)
```

## There are 3 places where the timezone might be set in MySQL:

Note: A timezone can be set in 2 formats:

1. an offset from UTC: '+00:00', '+10:00' or '-6:00'
2. as a named time zone: 'Europe/Helsinki', 'US/Eastern', or 'MET'

> Named time zones can be used only if the time zone information tables
> in the mysql database have been created and populated.

### in the file "my.cnf"

```
default_time_zone='+00:00'
```

or

```
timezone='UTC'
```

### @@global.time_zone variable

To see what value they are set to

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone;
```

To set a value for it use either one:

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+8:00';
SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Europe/Helsinki';
SET @@global.time_zone='+00:00';
```

### @@session.time_zone variable

```
SELECT @@session.time_zone;
```

To set it use either one:

```
SET time_zone = 'Europe/Helsinki';
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
SET @@session.time_zone = "+00:00";
```

both "@@global.time_zone variable" and "@@session.time_zone variable" might return "SYSTEM" which means that they use the timezone set in "my.cnf".

**For timezone names to work (even for default-time-zone) you must setup your timezone information tables need to be populated:** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html

Note: you can not do this as it will return NULL:

```
SELECT 
CONVERT_TZ(`timestamp_field`, TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP), '+00:00') AS `utc_datetime` 
FROM `table_name`
```

### Setup mysql timezone tables

For `CONVERT_TZ` to work, you need the timezone tables to be populated

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.`time_zone` ;
SELECT * FROM mysql.`time_zone_leap_second` ;
SELECT * FROM mysql.`time_zone_name` ;
SELECT * FROM mysql.`time_zone_transition` ;
SELECT * FROM mysql.`time_zone_transition_type` ;
```

If they are empty, then fill them up by running this command

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

if this command gives you the error "[data too long for column 'abbreviation' at row 1](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68861)", then it might be caused by a NULL character being appended at the end of the timezone abbreviation

the fix being to run this

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
(if the above gives error "data too long for column 'abbreviation' at row 1")
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo > /tmp/zut.sql

echo "SET SESSION SQL_MODE = '';" > /tmp/mysql_tzinfo_to.sql
cat /tmp/zut.sql >> /tmp/mysql_tzinfo_to.sql

mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my.cnf --user=verifiedscratch -p mysql < /tmp/mysql_tzinfo_to.sql
```

(make sure your servers dst rules are up to date `zdump -v Europe/Moscow | grep 2011` https://chrisjean.com/updating-daylight-saving-time-on-linux/)

### See the full DST (Daylight Saving Time) transition history for every timezone

```
SELECT 
tzn.Name AS tz_name,
tztt.Abbreviation AS tz_abbr,
tztt.Is_DST AS is_dst,
tztt.`Offset` AS `offset`,
DATE_ADD('1970-01-01 00:00:00',INTERVAL tzt.Transition_time SECOND)  AS transition_date
FROM mysql.`time_zone_transition` tzt
INNER JOIN mysql.`time_zone_transition_type` tztt USING(Time_zone_id, Transition_type_id)
INNER JOIN mysql.`time_zone_name` tzn USING(Time_zone_id)
-- WHERE tzn.Name LIKE 'Europe/Moscow' -- Moscow has weird DST changes
ORDER BY tzt.Transition_time ASC
```

`CONVERT_TZ` also applies any necessary DST changes based on the rules in the above tables and the date that you use.

**Note:**
According to the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html), the value you set for time_zone does not change, if you set it as "+01:00" for example, then the time_zone will be set as an offset from UTC, which does not follow DST, so it will stay the same all year round.

Only the named [timezones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) will change time during daylight savings time.

Abbreviations like `CET` will always be a winter time and `CEST` will be summer time while +01:00 will always be `UTC` time + 1 hour and both won't change with DST.

The `system` timezone will be the timezone of the host machine where mysql is installed (unless mysql fails to determine it)

You can read more about working with DST [here](https://web.ivy.net/%7Ecarton/rant/MySQL-timezones.txt)

When not to use UTC by the legendary Jon Skeet: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/
(For example a scheduled event in the future that represents a time, not an instant in time)

related questions:

- [How do I set the time zone of MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-timezone-of-mysql)
- [MySql - SELECT TimeStamp Column in UTC format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703793/mysql-select-timestamp-column-in-utc-format)
- [How to get Unix timestamp in MySQL from UTC time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515752/how-to-get-unix-timestamp-in-mysql-from-utc-time)
- [Converting Server MySQL TimeStamp To UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104903/converting-server-mysql-timestamp-to-utc)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20217/mysql-set-utc-time-as-default-timestamp
- [How do I get the current time zone of MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934258/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-zone-of-mysql)
- [MySQL datetime fields and daylight savings time -- how do I reference the "extra" hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646171/mysql-datetime-fields-and-daylight-savings-time-how-do-i-reference-the-extra)
- [Converting negative values from FROM_UNIXTIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587560/converting-negative-values-from-from-unixtime)

Sources:

- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68861
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time
- http://shafiqissani.wordpress.com/2010/09/30/how-to-get-the-current-epoch-time-unix-timestamp/
- [https://web.ivy.net/~carton/rant/MySQL-timezones.txt](https://web.ivy.net/%7Ecarton/rant/MySQL-timezones.txt)

Comment: So if I have my column type set to timestamp. And my time_zone is +12:00, and i want to update a column using a utc based date/time, is there any way to include the timezone in the update statement, or should i be using convert_tz. Eg. update `table` set `modified` = '2016-07-07 08:10 +00:00'

Comment: @bumperbox mysql always assumes that the date you are giving the timestamp column is in the same timezone as the mysql server, so you need to convert your date from your +12:00 timezone to your mysql server timezone for the update. This is why I use UTC on the mysql server and convert whatever date to UTC before storing it.

Comment: One of the best, most informative answers I've come across in years of using SO. Thank you.

Comment: WARNING!!! Any use of, or conversions from, the local time in a DST timezone will be wrong by an hour for an hour each year at the end of daylight savings.  This affects `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());` as well as all your uses of `CONVERT_TZ()` where one of the parameters is `@@session.time_zone.  For reliably converting UTC datetimes to UNIX timestamps, you basically have to set the session time_zone first.

Comment: @Flimm totally right, I forgot to fix that some time ago.

Comment: btw, curious if it is a good practice to store every time related stuff inside mysql using UTC (UTC +0), and read from mysql as UTC, then do the conversation to/from local time zone on the application side?

Comment: @hafan96 yes, it is good practice to store all as utc in mysql

Comment: FYI `MySQL 8.0.28` now supports timestamp that is beyond 2028

Answer (score 3):

PHP and MySQL have their own default timezone configurations. You should synchronize time between your data base and web application, otherwise you could run some issues.

Read this tutorial: [How To Synchronize Your PHP and MySQL Timezones](http://www.sitepoint.com/synchronize-php-mysql-timezone-configuration/)

Comment: It's basically two lines of code: `date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");` and `mysql_query("SET time_zone='" . date('P', time()) . "'");` Worked very elegantly!

Comment: @Noumenon Careful with that! I have been scratching my head this morning because that is exactly what I was doing, and some of my times are off by an hour now. What I suspect is that using a named timezone is more accurate when DST is involved. If you use America/New_York, MySQL knows about DST and will store dates appropriately. If you just set it to -04:00 like you have here, it will not take the DST calculation into consideration.

Comment: Do check if mysql knows about DST correctly, DST rules get regularly updated and the related mysql tables also need updating (see above at the bottom of my answer)

Answer (score 3):

This is a working example:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow
```

Answer (score 2):

The pros and cons are pretty much identical.It depends on whether you want this or not.

Be careful, if MySQL timezone differs from your system time (for instance PHP), comparing the time or printing to the user will involve some tinkering.

Answer (score 1):

How about making your app agnostic of the server's timezone?

Owing to any of these possible scenarios:

- You might not have control over the web/database server's timezone settings
- You might mess up and set the settings incorrectly
- There are so many settings as described in the other answers, and so many things to keep track of, that you might miss something
- An update on the server, or a software reset, or another admin, might unknowing reset the servers' timezone to the default - thus breaking your application

All of the above scenarios give rise to breaking of your application's time calculations. Thus it appears that the better approach is to make your application work independent of the server's timezone.

The idea is simply to always create dates in UTC before storing them into the database, and always re-create them from the stored values in UTC as well. This way, the time calculations won't ever be incorrect, because they're always in UTC. This can be achieved by explicity stating the `DateTimeZone` parameter when creating a PHP `DateTime` object.

On the other hand, the client side functionality can be configured to convert all dates/times received from the server to the client's timezone. Libraries like moment.js make this super easy to do.

For example, when storing a date in the database, instead of using the `NOW()` function of MySQL, create the timestamp string in UTC as follows:

```
// Storing dates
$date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$sql = 'insert into table_name (date_column) values ("' . $date . '")';

// Retreiving dates
$sql = 'select date_column from table_name where condition';
$dateInUTC = new DateTime($date_string_from_db, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

You can set the default timezone in PHP for all dates created, thus eliminating the need to initialize the DateTimeZone class every time you want to create a date.

Answer (score 0):

Check Timezone

**SELECT @@system_time_zone as System_tz ,@@global.time_zone as MYSQL_timeZone, NOW() as timenow_bymysql;**

**SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+05:30';**

OR

**change system time zone then restart MariaDB/MYSQL**

and check again timezone