# Unable to set the UTC timezone permamently

Tags: mysql, linux, opensuse

I am using this [time-zone-support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html) for setting the UTC timezone on my machine,
But the trouble is that I am not able to set it permanently, it changes to System time when I restart the MySQL server.

The box is OpenSuse 12.3, and the MySQL version is 5.5.33

```
mysql> SET time_zone = UTC;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
+--------------------+---------------------+
| @@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone |
+--------------------+---------------------+
| UTC                | UTC                 |
+--------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

now when I restart the mysql server, it reverts back to system.
After restarting the server:

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
+--------------------+---------------------+
| @@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone |
+--------------------+---------------------+
| SYSTEM             | SYSTEM              |
+--------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have tried doing the default time zone as well, but its giving me error.

```
mysql> default-time-zone=UTC;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'default-time-zone=UTC' at line 1
mysql>
```

Can someone please let me know what am I missing here, and how to set the UTC timezone permanently.

Comment: You cant set it in my.cnf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023978/should-mysql-have-its-timezone-set-to-utc

Comment: @Mihai I have added the following in the my.cnf file,default_time_zone='+00:00'
 restarted the mysql server and still time is the SYSTEM time :( is there a chance that my.cnf file is not getting read?

Comment: Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/930914/1745672

Comment: @Mihai thanks, I am wondering what will be the alternative of "$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata" in openSuse?

Comment: Sorry,Linux is not my thing.

Comment: @Mihai, thank you for your efforts, I have found the solution below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering my own question, as in the pursuit of the answer I have found the solution [here](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/498836-MSQL-Unable-to-set-the-UTC-timezone-permamently?p=2649103#post2649103)

I was editing my.cnf file and entering `default-time-zone = UTC` at the end of the file, as I did in windows machine, it does *NOT* work in Linux/Opensuse.

Then I entered `default-time-zone = UTC` in the `[mysqld]` section of the my.cnf, and the new time zone is picked up, and now the UTC timezone is set ***permanently***.

Comment: In mysql 5.6 on mac (using homebrew), "UTC" does not work