# Storing dates in Hibernate as UTC time dates?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date, datetime

I am facing an interesting question. On my local environment, I am on PDT time. When I store a UTC Date from my front end and right before I store the Date into my MySQL database through Hibernate, I check the date in Java prior to it being stored and the Date is actually converted into whatever my System's time zone was. I was really curious why this was even though my Date in the front end was formatted in UTC date, so I changed my System time zone from PDT to EDT and the date on in Hibernate ended up being in EDT time next time I tried to store that date. Is there any way I can change it so that in all environments, the Date is stored in as UTC time if it is not already in the UTC time zone?

Comment: Have you config anything related to timezone in mysql?

Comment: @dambros no I haven't. What do you suggest be the best way I do that? I have a column in my database that can be used to store time zone potentially.

Comment: Try the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql).

Answer (score 0):

**Back-end Side:**

MySQL having the `setTimestamp/getTimestamp` code, but it will only be enabled if you set the connection parameter `useLegacyDatetimeCode=false`, for further learning you can refer [this document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)

For example, if your database is set to use UTC, there might be several possible UTC time zones in Java, so you can clarify this for mysql-connector by telling it exactly what the database time zone is:

```
String url =
 "jdbc:mysql://localhost/databasename?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC+05:30";
```

**Client Side:**

Put below code in web.xml file, It will take your sytem timezone and display time in UTC on web page..

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and set UTC Timzone for MySQL you can refer this link [Should MySQL have its timezone set to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023978/should-mysql-have-its-timezone-set-to-utc/19075291#19075291)

Comment: Is there any way to actually change it so that it changes the timezone to UTC timezone instead of system timezone?

Comment: Set Your sytem timezone in UTC, Put above code in web.xml so it will show always system timezone to front end.

Comment: I actually want it so that the backend always stores UTC time the front end doesn't matter to me. I also don't want to change my system timezone

Comment: So you want to set UTC timezone in mysql using java?

Comment: Yes in my .MySQL database if possible

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate 5.2 simplifies this task as explained in [this article](http://in.relation.to/2016/09/12/jdbc-time-zone-configuration-property/).

Basically, you can now force the UTC time zone for all `TIMESTAMP` and `TIME` columns using the following configuration property:

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="UTC"/>
```