# How to display the right timestamp when select query in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I would like display the right timestamp of my query. The date in my database is this one and date timestamp is set in **Europe/Berlin**. That is in my server setup and I always get this result.

> 2017-05-26 09:05:58

I want to display the date from my query. here is the code of my query

```
select logs.action_date_time from AuditLogs
```

How can I convert the logs.action_date_time date in my place here in Philippines? I supposed to see this result

> 2017-05-26T09:05:58+02:00

I search it in google the unix_timestamp but I don't see any sample that they use in select before from query. I'm using symfony for this. I just give summary of what the result of my above sample code.

```
const SELECT =
        'SELECT logs.id, logs.object_id AS objectId, logs.object_type AS objectType, logs.object_name AS objectName, '.'logs.action, logs.action_date_time AS actionDateTime, logs.action_status AS actionStatus, logs.subject, logs.user, '.'logs.description, logs.ip, logs.param03_value AS userId, logs.param04_value AS userDisplayName ';

    public function getNext($params)
    {
        // Hardcode for now
        $limit = $params['limit'] ? (int) $params['limit'] : self::DEFAULT_LIMIT;
        $limit++;

        $select = self::SELECT;
        $whereClause = $this->constructWhereClause($params);

        $sql = "
            $select FROM spoke.audit_logs AS logs
            $whereClause
            ORDER BY logs.action_date_time DESC, logs.id DESC
            LIMIT $limit";

        if ($params['cursor']) {
            $now = new \DateTime();
            $datetime = $now->getTimestamp();
            if (isset($params['datetime'])) {
                $datetime = $params['datetime'];
            }
            $whereClause = $this->constructWhereClause($params, 'logs1', false);
            $sql = "
                $select
                FROM spoke.audit_logs logs1, spoke.audit_logs logs
                WHERE logs1.id = logs.id 
                    $whereClause
                    AND logs1.action_date_time <= '$datetime'
                    AND (logs1.id < {$params['cursor']} OR logs1.action_date_time < '$datetime')
                ORDER BY logs1.action_date_time DESC, logs1.id DESC
                LIMIT $limit";
        }
        $stmt = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->query($sql);

        return $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a UTC datetime column as a UNIX timestamp

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(`utc_datetime`, '+00:00', @@session.time_zone)) FROM `table_name`
```

Source is here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19075291/4511459)

Comment: I try to convert this but the time advance 2 hours.

Comment: but I try the link you give me

Answer (score 1):

You need to use MySQL's `CONVERT_TZ` function to convert the timezones, e.g.:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(action_date_time, 'CEST', 'PHT') FROM AuditLogs;
```

Alternatively, you can provide time zone difference as well, e.g.:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(action_date_time,'+01:00','+08:00') FROM AuditLogs;
```

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) the documentation.

Comment: If add this my select CONVERT_TZ(logs.action_date_time, 'CEST', 'PHT') AS actionDateTime and I found null in my response

Comment: @user3818576 added another query, try now?