# generate timezone specific date and time

Tags: mysql

My mysql query is as follows:

`select * from orders`

where `orders` has `created_at` field.

Now what i want is i want to convert created_at to **7 am of next day of created_at date** . and the time created should be according to **local timezone**.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Note:: and orders table also has field `timezone` which has values like **Australia/Sydney , Asia/Kolkata** etc.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Pretty sure when you read [Should MySQL have its timezone set to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023978/should-mysql-have-its-timezone-set-to-utc) solves your question or a great part of it.. ..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I am not talking about mysql timezone. that is why i mentioned timezone field in the note section of the question

Comment: *"I am not talking about mysql timezone. that is why i mentioned timezone field in the note section of the question "* Did you read the complete answer as you missed the main function  from that link as `CONVERT_TZ()` is used in there which can be used with table data and use table stored timezones -> *"Note:: and orders table also has field timezone which has values like Australia/Sydney , Asia/Kolkata etc."*..

Comment: See manual about using [CONVERT_TZ()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) -> *" Note

To use named time zones such as 'MET' or 'Europe/Amsterdam', the time zone tables must be properly set up. For instructions, see [Section 5.1.13, MySQL Server Time Zone Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html)"*

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through the `CONVERT_TZ` function

```
// syntax
CONVERT_TZ(your_timestamp_column_name, 'db_timezone', 'your_desired_timezone_name')

// Example
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(`created_at`, 'UTC', `timezone`) as `my_date` FROM orders
```

Now when you have a date in your desired timezone, you can add hour and time that comes from a difference of next day 7AM and `.my_date`