# Java - How do I prevent a LocalDate shifting back one day to MySQL Date?

Tags: java, mysql, date, timezone-offset

I googled around but didn't find an immediate solution.

- the data object has a LocalDate field
- the MySQL database has a matching DATE column

Date is created, for example:
`LocalDate d = LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 3);`

It's written to SQL as:
`stmt.setObject(1, d)); // or setDate with Date.valueOf(d)`

In SQL it's stored as UTC (I guess) so due to the offset (+1) it's now `2020-01-02` and also fetched as such.
(It obviously can't restore to the next day if DATE column doesn't store the hours.)

Comment: Are you sure the column in the database table is of type `DATE`? The db engine converting it due to an offset of some hours indicates a different type. Maybe `DATETIME` or even `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: this may help to diagnose your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023978/should-mysql-have-its-timezone-set-to-utc

Comment: Have you tried to set a `String` instead of an `Object`? You could try `stmt.setString(1, d.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);` and let the database convert it to a `DATE`.

Comment: @deHaar using the setString with the ISO_LOCAL_DATE formatter works, thank you! If you would provide that as answer, I'll gladly accept.

Comment: @FDM OK, cool... Glad it's working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set a `String` instead of an `Object` and let the database convert that to a `DATE`. This would basically look like

```java
LocalDate d = LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 3);
stmt.setString(1, d.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
```

This should keep the date values as they are (if working at all). The `Object` conversion could be a problem here.