# SQL Select data in the last 1 minutes

Tags: mysql, sql

i am currently practicing my SQL skills. I wanted to get all data in the past 1 minutes.

The query is `SELECT * FROM menfesses WHERE created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE;`
But somehow, it returns all data.

I have also use date_add approach and nothing works

What did i do wrong? Thanks

[image: Query Result]

Comment: The server time is 22.30. so it should not be within 1 minute

Comment: Wrap everything on the right of the >= in ()’s. Maybe it’s doing >= now which not much will be then subtracting the 1 minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your server time that's not what you think it is.

This work with a 5 min laps.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3711f2/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1
    (`c_date` datetime)
;
    
INSERT INTO t1
    (`c_date`)
VALUES
    (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE),
    (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE),
    (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *,NOW() FROM t1 WHERE c_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3711f2/1/0)**:

```
|               c_date |                NOW() |
|----------------------|----------------------|
| 2023-02-09T15:44:05Z | 2023-02-09T15:46:20Z |
| 2023-02-09T15:45:05Z | 2023-02-09T15:46:20Z |
```

Comment: Are there a way to patch the server current date with my inserted date? I've set the timezone to Jakarta and MySQL is still wrong

Comment: @farhandikazahrir you should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023978/should-mysql-have-its-timezone-set-to-utc or other subject like that. 2 points : 1) is your server on the good time ? 2) are the date you put in your table in the good time-zone.

Answer (score 0):

The last five minutes must be select with a BETWEEN.

Also testing you should add

```
SELECT created_at, Now() FROM menfesses WHERE created_at BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE AND NOW()
```

So that have a chance to debug it correctly

Between would only give you the correct data, as your test server could have dates later then now

## Edit

a fiddle demonstrates my point https://dbfiddle.uk/c5Jlko65

You maybe off on the system you have

Comment: tried to use it, somehow now it always returns 0 table. i tried to change it to 60 min still 0 table

Comment: then run the code without the where clause and  see what you got, times are always tricky